# facebook app, notify the user

Tags: facebook

I'm pretty new to facebook app. I want to make a simple app for learning. I want to create an app that visits mysite.com/page.json and prints some pretty html. Then i'd like to scan the json for 'private_message' and notify the user (and not publicly post on his/her wall) about the pm and print the message in their notification area.

The later is mostly what i want to learn. Where can i find the API reference? I looked at [fql/notification](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification) but it looks like its looking at the notifications when i want to post a notification.

Comment: This programming question was flagged as off-topic for Pro Webmasters (see [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq)) and will be migrated to StackOverflow. Please let us know at [Pro Webmasters Meta](http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/) if you have any questions regarding this question's migration.

Answer (score 1):

Applications cannot send private messages to users. Here is the [discussion about it on the facebook developers forums.](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=78135#p279982)
Applications only have read-only access to the message inbox with the `read_mailbox` permissions.

Comment: I think he's asking about app notifications, the world icon at the top of Facebook pages, not private inbox messages.

Comment: The person `acidzombie24` is himself not clear what he wants to do. He must have specified what is his requirement. Is it to send a private message or is it to notify.

Comment: The 'private_message' part was referring to my api/json data. I just want to notify the user on facebook. In a preferably not public way (so his/her friends cant see that she/he has a new msg, comment, etc)

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through as much documentation on this topic as I can find on the Facebook's developer portal, and all I can find are ways to read notifications (the world icon at the top of the page) and mark notifications as unread, but I can't find any way create them.  The best documentation I found on this topic was here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#notifications

Anyone have better information about this?